# Есть ли готовые плагины для Datepicker React?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui, ant-design

интересует вопрос про инпут с выбором даты. Есть ли какие-нибудь библиотеки для этого, где можно кастомизировать может, чтобы была кнопка "без даты" при выборе даты из календаря. Пользовалась Datepicker ant-design, react-date-picker и material-ui, там такой возможности нет.
Вот фото, что примерно я имею ввиду:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: Насколько я помню , в  datapicker можно стилизовать все. А вот по поводу добавления кнопки очень интересно. Можно попробовать в див с datapicker добавить обычную кнопку и стилизовать ее под календарь.

Comment: @datepicker-react/styled